# How to join 3 fields into 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing 3 columns which I would like to join together:

```
DECLARE @Clubs TABLE (ClubID INT IDENTITY, 
    ClubName NVARCHAR(50), 
    ClubNumber INT, 
    ClubState NVARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @Clubs (ClubName, ClubNumber, ClubState) 
VALUES
('Bellingham', 145, 'Texas'), 
('Bel-Air', 123, 'California');
```

So it would look something like this:

```
Bellingham - 145 - Texas
Bel-Air - 123 - California
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide specific details. For example: you talk about fields: where are these fields? Columns in a table? If so: what database. Also, what do you mean by "joining" 3 fields into 1 field: are you creating a new column in the database? Are you trying to return a single string as a value to your query? Then there's the question of whether you are trying to combine the three values within the query language or in code. You really need to show your work (code/inputs/outputs/errors) and clarify what you're trying to do (and what's not working)

Answer (score 0):

You can just concatenate the values:

```
DECLARE @Clubs TABLE (
    ClubID INT IDENTITY, -- not really needed here
    ClubName NVARCHAR(50), 
    ClubNumber INT, 
    ClubState NVARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @Clubs (ClubName, ClubNumber, ClubState) 
VALUES
('Bellingham', 145, 'Texas'), 
('Bel-Air', 123, 'California');

SELECT CONCAT( ClubName, ' - ', ClubNumber, ' - ', ClubState )
FROM @Clubs
```

Results:

```
Bellingham - 145 - Texas
Bel-Air - 123 - California
```